# Entity Framework many to many relationship insert not working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two tables with many to many relationship: `ActionPlan` and `Responsible`.

When I insert a new `ActionPlan` and new `Responsible`, the record on table `ActionPlanResponsible` is created correctly but when I try to add a new `ActionPlan` with existent `Responsible`, the record in table `ActionPlanResponsible` is not created.

I passing ActionPlan and Responsible inside a Json that way:

```
{

"What": "Whatttasdasdt",
"Why": "Whyasdyyyy",
"How": "Hoasdwwwww",
"StartDate": "28/09/2015",
"EndDate": "28/09/2015",
"CreateDate": "28/09/2015",
"UpdateDate": "28/09/2015",
"State": "1",
"Where" : "Whasdere",
"Goal": {
    "Id": "10"
},
"Responsibles": [{

    "Id": "15"
}]
```

That is the way I'm doing the request in EF...

```
foreach (var r in actionPlan.Responsibles)
{
    context.Responsible.Attach(r);
}

context.ActionPlan.Add(actionPlan); 

context.SaveChanges();
transaction.Commit();
```

The ActionPlan entity:

```
 public long Id { get; set; }

    public string What { get; set; }

    public string Why { get; set; }

    public string How { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Responsible> Responsibles { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public Goal Goal { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FileActionPlan> Files { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public string Where { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
```

The Responsible entity:

```
 public byte State { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<ActionPlan> ActionPlans { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
```

Comment: This question is very unclear to me.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated my question.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you included more of the method body and the definitions of the objects you're referencing (ie Reponsibles and ActionPlan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to add the `Responsibles` to `actionPlan.Responsibles`:

```
foreach (var r in actionPlan.Responsibles)
{
    context.Responsible.Attach(r);
    actionPlan.Responsibles.Add(r);
}

context.ActionPlan.Add(actionPlan);
```

This doesn't create new `Responsibles` but established the associations, so EF knows it should insert join records.